# Reloading View on Model Change

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I believe I'm aware of the problem i'm having; I just don't know how to resolve it. My view controller takes two parameters. When it's first loaded it gets one parameter and loads partial model. As soon as a selection is made from the grid on the page, the controller method is called again and the model is loaded with both parameters and returned to the view.

This all works perfectly, but when the additional data is added to the model it does not show up on screen. When I run it in debug I see the data in the view, it just doesn't show up on screen.

My guess is that this is because I need to reload the page, but I'm not entirely sure how to do that. Also, if anyone could comment and let me know if the workflow I'm using to accomplish the loading of additional data is correct, or if there is a better way.

Thanks!

**EventsController**

```
public class EventsController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Events/
    public ActionResult Events(string sName, int? iID)
    {
        ViewBag.AppName = sName;
        EventReader ereader = new EventReader(sName);
        Events _events = new Events();
        _events.LoggedEvents = ereader.GetListOfEvents().ToDataTable();
        //_events.EventDetails.Severity = "TEST";
        if (iID != null)
        {
            _events.EventDetails = ereader.GetEvent((int)iID);
        }

        return View(_events);
    }

    public ActionResult Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string sLogName)
    {
        EventReader ereader = new EventReader(sLogName);
        return this.Json(ereader.GetListOfEvents().ToDataTable().ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }
}
```

**Events.cshtml**

```
@model Models.Events

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Events for @ViewBag.AppName</h2>

<!-- HEADER GRID -->
<div id="Events">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.LoggedEvents)
          .Name("EventGrid")
          .Events(events => events.Change("eventGridHandler"))
          .Columns(columns =>
                       { 
                           columns.Bound("EntryType");
                           columns.Bound("EventDate");
                           columns.Bound("Source");
                           columns.Bound("ID");
                           //foreach (System.Data.DataColumn column in Model.Columns)
                           //{
                           //    columns.Bound(column.ColumnName);
                           //}
                       })
          .Pageable()
          .Sortable()
          .Selectable(select => select
                                    .Enabled(true)
                                    .Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single)
                                    .Type(GridSelectionType.Row)
          )
          .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                        .Ajax()
                                        .Model(model =>
                                                   {
                                                       model.Field("EntryType", typeof(string));
                                                       model.Field("EventDate", typeof(DateTime));
                                                       model.Field("Source", typeof(string));
                                                       model.Field("ID", typeof (int));                                                
                                                       model.Id("ID");
                                                       //foreach (System.Data.DataColumn column in Model.Columns)
                                                       //{
                                                       //    model.Field(column.ColumnName, column.DataType);
                                                       //}                
                                                   })
                                        .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Events")
                                                          .Data("eventGridBindingData")
                                        )
          ))
</div>

<!-- DETAIL AREA -->

<div id="EventDetail">
    <div id="Data">
        @(Html.TextArea("EventData", Model.EventDetails.EventData))
    </div>
    <div id="Details">
        <!-- Detail Table Goes Here -->
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>User</td>
                <td>Location</td>
                <td>Severity</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@(Model.EventDetails.UserID)</td>
                <td>@(Model.EventDetails.LocationID)</td>
                <td>@(Model.EventDetails.Severity)</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Page Scripts --> 
<script type="text/javascript">

    // Return additional data to the reader
    function eventGridBindingData() {
        return {
            name: '@ViewBag.AppName'
        };
    }

    // Handler for the EventGrid
    function eventGridHandler(e) {
        var data = this.dataItem(this.select());
        var appName = '@ViewBag.AppName';
        console.log("in event");
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'Events',
            data: { 'sName' : appName, 'iID' : data.id },
            type: "POST",
            cache: false
        });
    }

</script>
```

**Events.cs (model)**

```
public class Events
{
    #region PROPERTIES

    public DataTable LoggedEvents { get; set; }
    public CEventMessage EventDetails { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region CONSTRUCTORS

    public Events()
    {
        LoggedEvents = new DataTable();
        EventDetails = new CEventMessage();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your second question of whether this is the 'correct' way to go about solving the problem, I'd say probably not.

I'd rather use a separate action method 'EventDetails' to deliver the details of a given event Id. This will prevent the whole page being refreshed when the user actually wants to see the details of a given event. (Not to mention the unnecessary back-end chatter)

The view handling the details can also be a Kendo grid and you can use Kendo client side binding javascript to bind the returned event details (In JSON) to the detail grid.

To get a conceptual understanding of what I'm talking about please refer this [blog](http://www.uchithar.net/2012/11/the-grid-is-presentation-element-that.html) (I've written this for Telerik ASP.Net-MVC grid where they have the 'master-detail' baked in to the framework. Don't know whether Kendo supports this out of the box yet)